# DevExpress - MVVM - Generate TabItems with different ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, tabcontrol

i have a DXTabControl. The DXTabItems are generated via my ViewModel.

**//MainViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    var items = new ObservableCollection<DXTabItem>();
    items.Add(
        new DXTabItem()
        {
            Header = "Test1",
            Content = new WebViewModel()
        });

    items.Add(
        new DXTabItem()
        {
            Header = "Test2",
            Content = new CMSViewModel()
        });

    TabItems = items;
}

private ObservableCollection<DXTabItem> _tabItems;
public ObservableCollection<DXTabItem> TabItems
{
    get { return _tabItems; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _tabItems, value, () => TabItems); }
}
```

I am working with a DataTemplate and my TabItem is still not showing any UserControl.

**//MainView.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WebTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:WebViewModel}">
    <view:WebView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CMSTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:CMSViewModel}">
    <view:CMSView/>
</DataTemplate>

<datatemplate:TemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" 
                        WebTemplate="{StaticResource WebTemplate}"
                        CMSTemplate="{StaticResource CMSTemplate}" />

<dx:DXTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector}" />
```

**//DataTemplateSelector**

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate WebTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CMSTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(Object item,
        DependencyObject container)
    {

        if (item == null) return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        if (item.GetType() == typeof(WebViewModel))
        {
            return WebTemplate;
        }

        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CMSViewModel))
        {
            return CMSTemplate;
        }

        else return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

    }
}
```

Everything is working, except showing the content i need. No view is been shown. Any idea? Did i miss something?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I'm having the same problem today with DevExpress v14.1.

Comment: Hm yeah,somekind. I am working with caliburn.micro,you too? I can try to provide you an answer when i am at the office tomorrow. At the moment, i am on a smartphone.

Comment: I`m trying to figure out how to get a user control to appear in a tab item (not the header but in the content area). Not working with caliburn.micro.

Comment: Oh, if you are working with caliburn.micro, i give you sth useful ;) give me some hours ^^

Comment: my bad, i have interpreted your "not working with caliburn.micro" wrong. i am sorry for that. you should try it out. it makes your life easier. without caliburn.micro, i am not sure, but it should be doable. havent looked into it yet.

Comment: Hey Ray, i just looked at that topic without caliburn.micro again and it seems to work. i will edit my post and add an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is based on caliburn.micro.

Step 1: Add a convention to the bootstrapper

```
public Bootstrapper()
{
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<DXTabControl>(DXTabControl.ItemsSourceProperty, "ItemsSource", "DataContextChanged")
            .ApplyBinding = (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
        {
            if (!ConventionManager.SetBindingWithoutBindingOrValueOverwrite(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention, DXTabControl.ItemsSourceProperty))
            {
                return false;
            }
            var tabControl = (DXTabControl)element;
            if (tabControl.ItemTemplate == null && tabControl.ItemTemplateSelector == null && property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var itemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                if (!itemType.IsValueType && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(itemType))
                {
                    tabControl.ItemTemplate = ConventionManager.DefaultItemTemplate;
                }
            }

            ConventionManager.ConfigureSelectedItem(element, Selector.SelectedItemProperty, viewModelType, path);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tabControl.DisplayMemberPath))
            {
                ConventionManager.ApplyHeaderTemplate(tabControl, DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplateProperty, DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplateSelectorProperty, viewModelType);
            }
            return true;
        };

[...]
}
```

Now you can bind any Screen-Collection to your DXTabControl.

Step 2: Create a collection in the ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "DevExpress Test Environment";
    }


    private static BindableCollection<Screen> _tbCtrl = new BindableCollection<Screen>();
    public BindableCollection<Screen> TbCtrl
    {
        get { return _tbCtrl; }
        set
        {
            _tbCtrl = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TbCtrl);
        }
    }
}
```

You can e.g. put any other ViewModel which is based on the Screen class to your collection. That means, you will be able to display your content for each tabitem.

Step 3: Create the DXTabControl in your View (XAML-Code)

```
<dx:DXTabControl x:Name="TbCtrl" />
```

Give it a go. Open for feedback.

/// Alternative solution without Caliburn.Micro

Step 1: Add the DXTabControl to your MainView (XAML-Code)

```
<dx:DXTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TbCtrlItems}" />
```

Step 2: Your MainViewModel needs to add those items like i have described above (in my question), but in this case, you have to specify the content-property

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        _tbCtrlItems.Add(new DXTabItem()
        {
            Header = "Test1",
            Content = new Views.View1() {DataContext = new ViewModel1()}
        });

        _tbCtrlItems.Add(new DXTabItem()
        {
            Header = "Test2",
            Content = new Views.View2() { DataContext = new ViewModel2() }
        });


    }

    private ObservableCollection<DXTabItem> _tbCtrlItems = new ObservableCollection<DXTabItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<DXTabItem> TbCtrlItems
    {
        get { return _tbCtrlItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tbCtrlItems, value, () => TbCtrlItems); }
    }
```

I hope this answer is helpful.